# What's wrong with this Objective C self.navigationController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

What additional code do I need to add to make the below work?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    return YES;
}
```

It is currently throwing the error: `Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate`.

Comment: A property with the name `navigationController`...

Comment: What would that look like in the `.h` file (this is my first day learning obj-c). ?

Comment: you have navigation controller in your view?

Comment: `@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;` ?

Comment: Unless your app delegate is a subclass of `UIViewController` there is no navigation controller property. Maybe you mean to set your window's root view controller's navigation controller—assuming it has one?

Comment: where you are initializing navigationController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` belongs to your `AppDelegate`'s class, and `self` inside a method refers to the class that method belongs to. `AppDelegate` doesn't have the method `navigationController` that's why it complains.

You probably meant to run this code on the **root view controller**, not on the **app delegate**. Chance is that you initialized it somewhere in the same method, you just need to replace `self` with whatever variable that points to the root view controller:

```
[root view controller].navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```